# How to implement Haystack across all pages in website?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm creating a site like craigslist and need to implement a search feature where customers can search for a key term and see results. For example, searching for "lamp" will create a result page with all the posts that are related to lamps.

I'm using Haystack / Solr to search the contents. However, at the moment, users have to go to a specific search page where they can then narrow their results.

How do I implement it in such a way that the search bar can appear in my header on every page? I'm using Django.

Comment: So the question is more about django-templates than haystack? I'll retag it - feel free to tag it back if we're wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to have all pages extend a base template. So you can have one template (e.g. `base.html`) that contains the basic structure of your site (headers, footers, boilerplate). Then you can extend this template for each page of your site. (i.e. `{% extends 'base.html' %}`).

Following this structure, you should be able to put your search form in the base template and have it appear on all pages.